# Performance issue in combined where clauses

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

**Question**

I would like to know: How can I rewrite/alter my search query/strategy to get an acceptable performance for my end users?

**The search**

I'm implementing a search for our users, they are provided the ability to search for candidates on our system based on:

- A professional group they fall into,
- A location + radius,
- A full text search.

**The query**

```
select v.id
    from (
        select
            c.id,
            c.ts_description,
            c.latitude,
            c.longitude,
            g.group
        from entities.candidates c
        join entities.candidates_connections cc on cc.candidates_id = c.id
        join system.groups g on cc.systems_id = g.id
    ) v

    -- Group selection
    where v.group = 'medical'

    -- Location + radius
    and earth_distance(ll_to_earth(v.latitude, v.longitude), ll_to_earth(50.87050439999999, -1.2191283)) < 48270

    -- Full text search
    and v.ts_description @@ to_tsquery('simple', 'nurse | doctor')
;
```

**Data size & benchmarks**

I am working with 1.7 million records

I have the 3 conditions in order of impact which were benchmarked in isolation:

- Group clause: 3s & reduces to 700k records
- Location clause: 8s & reduces to 54k records
- Full text clause: 60s+ & reduces to 10k records

When combined they seem to take 71s, which is the full impact of the 3 queries in isolation, my expectation was that when putting all 3 clauses together they would work sequentially i.e on the subset of data from the previous clause therefore the timing should reduce dramatically - but this has not happened.

**What I've tried**

- All join conditions & where clauses are indexed
- Notably the ts_description index (GIN) is 2GB
- lat/lng is indexed with ll_to_earth() to reduce the impact inline
- I nested each where clause into a different subquery in order
- Changed the order of all clauses & subqueries
- Increased the shared_buffers size to increase the potential cache hits

Comment: Can you add the explain plan?

Comment: It seems you do not need a subquery

Answer (score 0):

It seems you do not need to subquery, and it is also a good practice to filter with numeric fields, so, instead of filtering with `where v.group = 'medical'` for example, create a dictionary and just filter with `where v.group = 1`

```
        select
            DISTINCT c.id,
        from entities.candidates c
        join entities.candidates_connections cc on cc.candidates_id = c.id
        join system.groups g on cc.systems_id = g.id
    where tablename.group = 1
    and earth_distance(ll_to_earth(v.latitude, v.longitude), ll_to_earth(50.87050439999999, -1.2191283)) < 48270
    and v.ts_description @@ to_tsquery(0, 1 | 2)
```

also, use `EXPLAIN ANALYSE` to see and check your execution plan. These quick tips will help you improve it clearly.

Answer (score 0):

There were some best practice cases that I had not considered, I have subsequently implemented these to gain a substantial performance increase:

**tsvector Index Size Reduction**

I was storing up to 25,000 characters in the tsvector, this meant that when more complicated full text search queries were used there was just an immense amount of work to do, I reduced this down to 10,000 which has made a big difference and for my use case this is an acceptable trade-off.

**Create a Materialised View**

I created a materialised view that contains the join, this offloads a little bit of the work, additionally I built my indexes on there and run a concurrent refresh on a 2 hour interval. This gives me a pretty stable table to work with.

Even though my search yields 10k records I end up paginating on the front-end so I only ever bring back up to 100 results on the screen, this allows me to join onto the original table for only the 100 records I'm going to send back.

**Increase RAM & utilise pg_prewarm**

I increased the server RAM to give me enough space to store my materialised view into, then ran pg_prewarm on my materialised view. Keeping it in memory yielded the biggest performance increase for me, bringing a 2m query down to 3s.

Comment: I won't mark this as the correct answer because increasing the performance will depend on what trade-offs you can make in your solution. Some, all or none of the points in my answer may apply to you.